# MatMul issue in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm trying to implement multilayer perceptron in TensorFlow with 4D-numpy array data
I got this issue on MatMul function. 
I hope someone can help me here and thank you so much.

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 4 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [1500,2,10000,5], [1500,1500].
```

My code is:

```
# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 1500 # 1st layer number of neurons
n_hidden_2 = 1500 # 2nd layer number of neurons
n_input = 1500 
n_classes = 1500

# tf Graph input
X = tf.placeholder("float", [1500,2,10000,5])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [1500,1])

# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}


# Create model
def multilayer_perceptron(x):

    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])

    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])

    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer

    # Construct model
    logits = multilayer_perceptron(X)
```

The second error is :

```
ValueError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 1500 and 1 for 'cost/SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits' (op: 'SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits') with input shapes: [1500,1500], [1500,1].
```

the code is:

```
p_keep_input = tf.placeholder("float", name="p_keep_input")
p_keep_hidden = tf.placeholder("float", name="p_keep_hidden")
py_x = model(X, w_h, w_h2, w_o, p_keep_input, p_keep_hidden)

with tf.name_scope("cost"):
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=py_x, labels=Y))
    train_op = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001, 0.9).minimize(cost)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dense layers you usually start with reshaping your input data to be one row per sample, so a `[nSamples, nFeatures]` matrix (with 2 dimensions, not 4), since you won't be using the structure. Only this allows the MatMul to happen correctly (it's now a multiplication of two 2D matrices).

I guess here `nSamples = n_inputs = 1500`, and `nFeatures = 2*10000*5`. In that case, be careful that `h1` needs to be of shape `[nFeatures, n_hidden_1]`.

```
n_features = 2*10000*5
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_features, n_hidden_1])),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_classes]))
}
```

...

```
def multilayer_perceptron(x):
    x_reshaped = tf.reshape(x, [None, n_features])
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x_reshaped, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
```

By the way, for easier debugging, you should use different n_inputs, n_hidden, n_classes (you may have no choice for n_classes but you can change the others), that way you'll understand more easily the shaping errors (whereas here when you see a shape of 1500 you don't know immediately where it comes from, so it's more confusing, and it may even be there for bad reasons and cause trouble later).

**Answer to the 2nd problem (edit):**

[`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) expects both logits and labels of the same [n_samples, n_classes] shape, the labels being one-hot encoded just like the logits (except they'll usually consist only of one 1 and zeros). If Y is of shape [n_samples, 1], then I expect it just contains the class index for each sample.In this case, you should use [`sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) instead, and Y should be of shape `[n_samples]` only, not `[n_samples, 1]`.

Comment: I got an other error. I will add it in my question.

Comment: I've answered it. In the future please post new arrising questions in another post, since they are different problems, so that you can accept the first answer and get more attention on the new error. And you should definetely not use equal numbers everywhere (your 1500 for n_samples, n_classes, n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2). Even if you use 1500, 1499, 1498, 1497, it will have almost exactly the same behavior, but you'll know much faster if your shapes are what they should be.

Comment: Thank you so so much again for your answer! It was a good practice for me as a beginner in Machine Learning and TensorFlow . 
That's helps me a lot

Comment: Glad I could help you ! Please accept the answer if the problem is resolved, both for my rep and the future people who might see this facing the same issue.

Comment: When attempting to use `tf.reshape(x, [None, n_features])` I get `TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <type 'list'> to Tensor`